# Python modify column in a CSV to muliple columns

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns

I'm trying to modify one column in a CSV, to change it to multiple columns.
Hence this CSV:

```
title,body,field_tag,field_titel
--------------------------------
"bladibla", "bla.....bla", "[""tag1"",""tag2"",""tag3"",""tag4""]", "bladiblabla"
"bladibla", "bla.....bla", "[""tag3"",""tag4"",""tag5"",""tag7"",""tag8"",""tag11""]", "bladiblabla"
```

What I want is this:

```
title,body,field_titel,field_tag,field_tag,field_tag,field_tag,field_tag,field_tag
--------------------------------
"bladibla","bla.....bla","bladiblabla","tag1,"tag2","tag3","tag4"
"bladibla","bla.....bla","bladiblabla","tag3,"tag4","tag5","tag7","tag8","tag11"
```

How to achieve this in Python? 
What i've tried so far is this, but not given the result i want.

```
import csv
import numpy

with open('tester.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('testeroutput.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        all = []
        rij = next(reader)

        for row in reader:
            # print row['field_tag']
            strlist = row[3]
            #remove [ and ]
            strlist = (strlist.replace('[', ''))
            strlist = (strlist.replace(']', ''))

            text = strlist.split(',')

            #make string of list
            for tag in text:
                str1 = ''.join(tag)
                print str1
                print(type(str1))

                row.append('field_tag')
                all.append(row)
                row.append(str1)
                all.append(row)

        writer.writerows(all)
```

Hope that you can point me in a better direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize this snippet:

```
import ast

for row in reader:
    row.extend(ast.literal_eval(row.pop(2)))
    writer.writerow(row)
```

`row.pop(2)` removes the third item from the row and returns it.    [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) safely evaluates that third item as long as it contains "Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None."